# LoadMask image - extjs

Tags: image, load, extjs4, mask

I have used mask on loading in my view.
   Right now it is showing me default loading image (x-mask-loading)
   I want to add my own image instead of that default image.
   Can anybody having some idea?
   Please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change loading icon by appliing css rules to loadMask Element (see [loadingCls](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-cfg-loadingCls) config):

```js
Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
    loadingCls: 'custom-loader'
    // ...
});
```

```css
/* CSS */
.x-mask-msg .custom-loader {
    background-image: url(http://example.com/custom-loading.gif);
}
```

Check out a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/frzk8/).

#### UPDATE

> This doesn't work anymore with extjs 4.2. Checkout the new [version](http://jsfiddle.net/eC39Q/). Any idea how to fix this?

This is strange but sencha doesn't provide api (at least I didn't find one) for changing loadMask icon. So the only option is to fiddle with css again:

```css
/* CSS */
.x-mask-msg .custom-loader .x-mask-msg-text {
    background-image: url(http://example.com/custom-loading.gif);
}
```

[ExtJs4.2 demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eC39Q/1).

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with extjs 4.2. Checkout the new [version](http://jsfiddle.net/eC39Q/). Any idea how to fix this?